# Remover palavra duplicada em texto: "...período de tolerância termina *em em..."

Tags: bug, tradução

O texto apresenta uma palavra duplicada (negrito):

> [fulano] oferecia +100 pontos de reputação como recompensa nesta pergunta, até 5 horas atrás. O período de tolerância termina **em em** [x] horas

Answer (score 2):

Adicionei a sugestão no Transifex. Falta a revisão do chefe ainda.